# Using multithreading for pathfinding

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, a-star

I am coding my own game using my own engine in direct3D. I know almost nothing about multithreading. The thing is that my enemies use A-star to follow the player, and the performance is pretty good. Even so, I would like to improve the performance even more. That's why I want to use multitreading. My goal is to process pathfinding in a different thread while the game keeps updating. Ok so taking into account that OrderPath is a std::future type variable, this is the code:

```
void EnemyWaveManager::DoPath()
{
    for (auto& enemie : Enemy::Enemies)
    {
        enemie->FindComponentByType<EnemyAI>()->ComputePath();
    }
}
void EnemyWaveManager::Update()
{
    if (ThreadIsReady(OrderPath))
    {
        OrderPath = std::async(std::launch::async, &EnemyWaveManager::DoPath, this);
    }
}
```

and this is my ThreadIsReady implementation:

```
template<typename T> inline
bool ThreadIsReady(std::future<T> const& f)
{
    return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready;
}
```

Ok so the enemies compute properly the path the first 3 seconds but then it stops working. The thread never finishes so it doesn't order more pathfinding. Moreover, sometimes I get acces violation errors inside the pathfinding function, which is strange because it only uses local variables.

Comment: Is `Enemy::Enemies` mutable? If it is then you have data race.

Comment: If your problem is small lag spikes, I have had this problem too. My workaround is to calculate my pathfinding between frames.